# How to deal with subclass when instances of original class are generated by method from another class?

Tags: python, subclass, monkeypatching, class-method

I have a small application I'm making and am having trouble figuring out how to implement this one part to it. In principle, the issue here is that I need to add a method to a class. However, the instances of that class are generated through a method in another class. I am therefore unclear how to implement the subclass without also creating a subclass of the second class.

More specifically, the two classes are: 
PlotItem and GraphicsLayoutWidget (classes from pyqtgraph - abbreviate pg below).

So, in my application I have:

```
self.plotWidget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget
```

instances of the PlotItem class are generated by calling the addPlot() method from GraphicsLayoutWidget. I.E.:

```
plt = self.plotWidget.addPlot(*args)
```

The problem is I need to add a method to the PlotItem class, which I had planned on doing by just subclassing it. However, I then don't know how to generate instances of that without also subclassing GraphicsLayoutWidget.

Is that the best solution? I've read a bit about just monkey patching the method into the PlotItem class, but I'm in general unfamiliar with this approach (relatively new to all of this).

In case it's relevant, the (simplified) subclass definition:

```
class MyPlotItem(PlotItem):
    def paint(self, painter, *args):
        painter.setPen(...)
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
        PlotItem.paint(self, painter, *args)
```

Comment: I see nothing bad in inheriting GraphicsLayoutWidget. That gives you more control on what's happening and makes code easier to read.

Comment: If you monkeypatch the `PlotItem` class, then your `paint` method will be used by *all* plot-items, rather than just the ones you add via `addPlot`. To avoid this, you could monkeypatch `PlotItem` *instances* instead. But, really, the most natural approach is to subclass both `GraphicsLayoutWidget` and `PlotItem`.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your class a new constructor which creates a `MyPlotItem` instance from a `PlotItem`, e.g.:

```
class MyPlotItem(PlotItem):

    @classmethod
    def from_plotitem(cls, plotitem):
        return cls(plotitem.parent, plotitem.name, ...)

    def paint(self, painter, *args):
        painter.setPen(...)
        painter.drawRect(self.boundingRect())
        PlotItem.paint(self, painter, *args)
```

Then you can replace:

```
plt = self.plotWidget.addPlot(*args)
```

with:

```
plt = MyPlotItem.from_plotitem(self.plotWidget.addPlot(*args))
```

and have an instance with the desired method.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue where I wanted to subclass `PlotItem` in order to trigger a signal when it was clicked.

Instead of having to subclass `GraphicsLayoutWidget` and then use `addPlot()` I made use of `GraphicsLayoutWidget`'s `addItem()` function as follows:

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys

class myPlotItem(pg.PlotItem):

    clicked = pyqtSignal(QObject)

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(myPlotItem, self).__init__(parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, ev):
        super(myPlotItem, self).mousePressEvent(ev)
        self.clicked.emit(self)

def on_click(plot):
    print 'clicked! ' + str(plot)


app = QApplication([])

figure = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
plot = myPlotItem()
plot.clicked.connect(on_click)
figure.addItem(plot)
figure.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This works happily because `addPlot()` itself calls `addItem()` in the same way once it has created the `PlotItem`:

http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/_modules/pyqtgraph/graphicsItems/GraphicsLayout.html#GraphicsLayout.addPlot